# Google Sheets - Automatically record values from Sheet 1 to Sheet 2 on a specific day and time of the week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a form that gathers the amount hours each member of a team has dedicated to a specific task on one sheet, and it changes every week. These values are deleted every Monday I need to create a record of these values on a new sheet every Sunday, to keep a record. I have a code that would take the values from a cell and paste it in the first available row in that same sheet, But I need it to paste it in a different sheet.

The code I have is this:

```
function recordValue() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var date = new Date();
    var value =sheet.getRange("K6").getValue();
    sheet.appendRow([date, value]);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function recordValue() {
   var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
   var date = new Date();
   var value =sheet.getRange("K6").getValue();
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OtherSheetName").appendRow([date, value]);
}
```

or

```
function recordValue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var values = [new Date()]
  sheet.getRange("K6:K10").getValues().forEach(v => values.push(v[0]));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OtherSheetName").appendRow(values);
}
```

or

```
function recordValue() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var dest = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OtherSheetName");
  var range = "K6:K10";
  dest.getRange(range).setValues(sheet.getRange(range).getValues());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, this works! If you don´t mind, what if I wanted to record the values in several cells, say from K6 to K10?

Comment: take the second script and let me know of everything is ok

Comment: I am sorry, because I am really bad at this and the solution is probably as easy as the rest, but the last solution is recording the values in the same row and different columns. I'd like it to preserve the order, getting the values on sheet1, K6:K10 and putting them on Sheet2, K6:K10. Is that possible?

Comment: take the third script